# GWT widget with JSNI not attached yet

Tags: gwt, jsni

I created a widget that extends SimplePanel and execute some JSNI in onLoad() method:

```java
public class AceEditor extends SimplePanel implements HasText {

  private JavaScriptObject editor;

  @Override
  protected void onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();
    editor = createEditor(getElement());
  }

  private static native JavaScriptObject createEditor(Element element) /*-{
      return $wnd.ace.edit(element);
  }-*/;

  @Override
  public native void setText(String value) /*-{
      this.@org.obiba.opal.web.gwt.ace.client.AceEditor::editor.setValue(value);
  }-*/;

  @Override
  public final native String getText() /*-{
      return this.@org.obiba.opal.web.gwt.ace.client.AceEditor::editor.getValue();
  }-*/;

}
```

The problem is when I call `setText` for the first time, the widget is not attached yet (`onLoad` was not called yet).

I use this widget with `UiBinder`.

I could use `addAttachHandler` and check if the widget is attached but it does not seem the right way to do it...

Any idea of why the widget is not attached sooner?

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the call to createEditor in the constructor instead of onload ?

It seems that your code is calling the setText before the page is loaded.
Now if that is the case calling createEditor in the constructor should be proper.

Comment: It seems to work but I thought that JS initialization had to be done in `onLoad` and not in the constructor because the `div` of the widget was not attached to the DOM yet.

Comment: What you said is true provided your JS is referring to other elements on the DOM which it cannot access before page load . But in your case it is more a construction of ur object .In other words your AceEditor is of not much use without the editor itself.Also you have the setText  method called before onload, so it means some other object already needs your AceEditor befor epage load

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea of why the widget is not attached sooner?

By definition, it shouldn't be 'attached' until after you've added it to an already-attached parent (either to `RootPanel`, or another thing already added to `RootPanel`). Have you done so and `onLoad` still isn't called?

If your JS tool (in this case `ace`) requires that a DOM node exists, then you don't need to wait for `onLoad` to be called to do anything - as of your Widget subclass's constructor being finished, you must already have specified an element.

If you actually require that this element is attached to the document before you can perform operations on it, then yes, of course, you need to wait until onLoad is called.